Simple probability question - seeming contradiction
Set up
Consider a collection of random events $A_1, \dots, A_n$ and $B_1, \dots, B_n$. It is clear from Bayes rule that
$$
P(A_i \mid B_i) = \frac{P(B_i \mid A_i) P(A_i)}{P(B_i)},
$$
for each $i=1,\dots,n$. Therefore by summing we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i \mid B_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{P(B_i \mid A_i) P(A_i)}{P(B_i)}. \tag{1}
$$
Now, we establish another fact. Define $I \sim \mathrm{unif}\{1, \dots, n\}$ independent of all events. Then by Bayes rule
$$
P(A_I \mid B_I) = \frac{P(B_I \mid A_I) P(A_I)}{P(B_I)}.
$$
Expanding each of these terms using the law of total probability, we see e.g. that $P(B_I) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i)$ and
$$
P(A_I \mid B_I) 
= \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i \mid B_i, I=i) P(I=i)
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i \mid B_i) \tag{?}
$$
and likewise for $P(B_I \mid A_I)$ and $P(A_I)$. Plugging this into the previous display, we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i \mid B_i) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i \mid A_i) \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i)}. \tag{2}
$$
Consequence and confusion
By equating the RHS terms in eqs. (1) and (2), we get
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i \mid A_i) \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n P(B_i)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{P(B_i \mid A_i) P(A_i)}{P(B_i)}. 
$$
These two expressions in eq. (3) are clearly not always equal, indicating an error in the previous development. I can't find it, however I am suspicious of eq. (?). Would someone please point out the error? Thanks.

Such a well elaborated question for a new member. Congratulations!

The problem is indeed in (?). Here you are applying the law of total probability to a conditional probability space, but not quite correctly. It should be
$$P(A_I\mid B_I)=\sum_{i=1}^nP(A_I\mid B_I,I=i)P(I=i\mid B_I).$$

Earlier, I made an answer claiming that this was a common mistake made in probability. Seems like I wasn't wrong!
